# C++ - Null Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm learning about pointers in C++. I wrote this simple program to show what I had a problem with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "test1";
    char *ptr = 0;
    cout << ptr;
    cout << "test2";
}
```

When I run the program, it doesn't output "test2" at the end, instead only "test1". This should mean that it crashed when I tried to print out the value of ptr? I tried stepping through it in Eclipse debugger and it looks like every line gets executed but doesn't it throw an error or something?

Comment: For starters, try this: cout << "test2" << endl; And see if it prints out test2.  The previous line should print out the address of ptr.

Comment: You are right -- sorry for my bad semantics.  I'm not sure if it's implementation-defined though.  I use this regularly with GCC on OSX & Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *ptr = 0;
cout << ptr;
```

There's an overload of the `<<` operator that takes a `char*` operand, which it assumes is a pointer to a C-style string.

For pointer types other than `char*`, the `<<` operator would print the value of the pointer (which is an address), but treating a null `char*` pointer as if it pointed to a C-style string causes undefined behavior. In any case, it's not going to print the pointer value.

To print the pointer value, you can convert it to `void*`:

```
cout << "test1\n";
char *ptr = 0;
cout << static_cast<void*>(ptr) << "\n";
cout << "test2" << "\n";;
```

Comment: I believe static_cast is best here.

Comment: I can say that at least in C++11, *Requires: s shall not be a null pointer.* ergo no check. C++03 is the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can output a pointer to cout and it will print the address contained. However, when you output a `char *` it is interpreted as a C-style null-terminated string. In this case, it's a null pointer and does not point to a string.

Try casting it to a `void *` before outputting it.